# Handling the view count in the wagtail page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

According to the user tracking analysis, I have been created a tracking method to save TrackUserRest record and update the Restaurant.view_count.

The version 1 pop up an error when imported into Restaurant models.
The version 2 save record and updates the view_count amount successfully, but I am not sure that it is the right way?

For the further enhancement study, can anyone get me some examples to update the wagtail page in the right way?

sorry for my English.

```
class RestaurantPage(Page)
    .... #other attribute
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,
                                             editable=False)

    @property
    def restaurant_page(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['restaurant_page'] = self.restaurant_page
        context['restaurant'] = self
        self.tracking(request)
        return context

    def tracking(self, request):
        track = TrackUserRest()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            track.user_id = request.user.id
        else:
            track.user_id = 0
        track.restaurant_id = self.pk
        track.time = timezone.now()
        track.save()
        self.view_count = self.view_count+1
        return super(RestaurantPage, self).save()
```

```
# version 1
# dashboard.models
from accounts.models import ExtendedUser
from restaurant.models import RestaurantPage

class TrackUserRest(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('time', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Restaurant Tracking system: usee.id({}) viewed rest.id({}) at timezone.({})'.format(self.user,
                                           self.rest.title,
                                           self.time)

#  Error msg
#  File "<path>/restaurant/models.py", line 19, in <module>
#    from dashboard.models import TrackUserRest
#  File "<path>/dashboard/models.py", line 3, in <module>
#    from restaurant.models import RestaurantPage
#  ImportError: cannot import name 'RestaurantPage' from 'restaurant.models' (<path>/restaurant/models.py)
```

```
#version 2
# dashboard.models
class TrackUserRest(models.Model):
    user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    restaurant_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('time', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Restaurant Tracking system: user.id({}) viewed rest.id({}) at timezone.({})'.format(self.user,
                                           self.rest.title,
                                           self.time)
```

Comment: What error did you get from version 1?

Comment: The TrackUserRest models link to customize user model and restaurantPage mode.
It will raise an error when I visit the restaurantPage.

I have been updated the error code on the bottom of version 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1 is failing because you have a circular import - `TrackUserRest` depends on `RestaurantPage` being defined, but `RestaurantPage` depends on `TrackUserRest` being defined, so there's no way for Python to decide which one comes first.

The simplest way to fix this is to use a string version of the model name when defining the ForeignKey, so that there's no need to import RestaurantPage:

```
from accounts.models import ExtendedUser

class TrackUserRest(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_id = models.ForeignKey('restaurant.RestaurantPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's work for me. And can you get me some examples to update the wagtail page in the right way? Like the view count in the Wagtail page.